# Help in identifying a Thai condiment

Tags: food-identification, spicy-hot, thai-cuisine, condiments

At my favorite local Thai restaurant, they have a trio of spicy condiments available to add to your food. Of the three, one is chile-garlic sauce, one is a crushed dried red pepper of some kind, and the third is very mysterious to me.

It is a thick, dark (nearly black) chunky "paste" (ok, to chunky to be a paste, but I don't have a better word for it... 'jam' maybe?).

It is clearly made primarily of chilis, and I believe some kind of oil, but I'm not sure what else might be in it.

It has a very interesting flavour -- kind of roasty and spicy? Maybe some garlic in there too?

Any ideas as to what this mysterious roasty black chili "jam" might be?

In googling for Thai condiments, I keep finding several standard condiments, but none of them are this.

(I guess I could ask at the restaurant, but where's the fun in that? Plus I always forget when I am there...)

Comment: So is it spicy hot? Tangy? Sweet? Some more description will help narrow down the item.

Comment: It's certainly spicy-hot -- some kind of chili is a main ingredient for sure, but it's also got a kind of burnt taste? Maybe? I'm thinking maybe it's something made from roasted chilis and garlic and oil... But, like, roasted to the point of black. But that's just a guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it [roasted chili paste](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&q=roasted%20chili%20paste) (น้ำพริกเผา in Thai)?

Comment: I believe this is probably correct answer based on your description. Mae Pranom is a very popular Thai brand.

Comment: To follow up, a few years later, i just came across a blog post that confirmed this answer: http://shesimmers.com/2011/01/nam-prik-pao-thai-chilli-jam-secret.html it is definitely nam prik pao.

Answer (score 2):

Thai Black Bean Sauce? (see e.g. [this recipe](http://www.tastebook.com/recipes/1428834-Thai-Black-Bean-Sauce))